# Man move from source to destination with constraints

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Consider this cartesian graph where each index represents a weight.

[3, 2, 1, 4, 2

1, 3, 3, 2, 2

**S**, 3, 4, 1, **D**

3, 1, 2, 4, 3

4, 2, 3, 1, 4]

A man is standing at source 'S' and he has to reach destination 'D' at minimum cost. Constraints are:

1. If the man moves from one index to another index where both index share same cost, the cost of moving man is '1'.
2. If the man moves from one index to another index where both indexes have different cost, the cost of moving man is abs(n-m)*10 + 1.
3. Last but not the least, man can only move up, down, left & right. No diagonal moves.

Which data structure & algorithm is best suited for this problem. I have thought of representing this problem as a graph and use one of the greedy approaches but could not reach to clean solution in my mind.

Comment: Is 'the robot' and 'the man' the same thing? What are `m` and `n` in the second case; are they the node cost of the two nodes?

Comment: @Codor, I should have cleared that. Thanks for pointing it out. Yes, man and robot is the same thing. 'm' and 'n' are the node cost of two nodes.

Comment: @maraca, Thanks for writing. The cost for S and D are '1'. Also, I have added one more constraint in the question. Please look and suggest.

Comment: What is preventing you from using standard shortest path algorithm like Dijakstra? All edge costs are known, are  positive and you have sparse graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use A* to solve the problem. The distance can be estimated by dx + dy + 10 * dValue + distance travelled (it is impossible that the way is shorter than that, see example at the bottom). The idea of A* is to expand always the node with the lowest estimated distance, as soon as you find the destination node you are finished. This works if the estimation never over-estimates the distance. Here is an implementation in JS ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nkojdun/2/)):

```js
function solve(matrix, sRow, sCol, eRow, eCol) {
    if (sRow == eRow && sCol == eCol)
        return 0;
    let n = matrix.length, m = matrix[0].length;
    let d = [], dirs = [[-1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1]];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        d.push([]);
        for (let j = 0; j < m; j++)
            d[i].push(1000000000);
    }
    let list = [[sRow, sCol, 0]];
    d[sRow][sCol] = 0;
    for (;;) {
        let pos = list.pop();
        for (let i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++) {
            let r = pos[0] + dirs[i][0], c = pos[1] + dirs[i][1];
            if (r >= 0 && r < n && c >= 0 && c < m) {
                let v = d[pos[0]][pos[1]] + 1 + 10 * Math.abs(matrix[pos[0]][pos[1]] - matrix[r][c]);
                if (r == eRow && c == eCol)
                    return v;
                if (v < d[r][c]) {
                    d[r][c] = v;
                    list.push([r, c, v + Math.abs(r - eRow) + Math.abs(c - eCol) + 10 * Math.abs(matrix[r][c] - matrix[eRow][eCol])]);
                }
            }
        }
        list.sort(function(a, b) {
            if (a[2] > b[2])
                return -1;
            if (a[2] < b[2])
                return 1;
            return 0;
        });
    }
}
```

The answer for the example is 46 and only 8 nodes are getting expanded!

Estimation example, from (0,0) to D:

- distance from S to (0,0) is 22
- dx = abs(0 - 4) = 4
- dy = abs(0 - 2) = 2
- dValue = abs(3 - 1) = 2
- estimation = distance + dx + dy + 10 * dValue = 22 + 4 + 2 + 10 * 2 = 48

Note: the implementation uses rows and columns insted of x and y, so they are swapped, it doesn't really matter it just has to be consistent.

Comment: Whoa! Although I did not understand the logic behind it, I would still say 'Thanks for writing it out'. It would be even nicer if you could explain what you did.

Actually, I was expecting something in terms of 'graphs'.

Comment: @HemantBhargava added more explanation, the wikipedia article is pretty good and the animation very nice https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Astar_progress_animation.gif (linked the wrong one before).

Comment: Thanks for downvote. Can you explain? It gives the correct result and is more efficient than the other proposed method. @downvoter

Answer (score 1):

Although not explicitly stated, in the problem formulation there seem to be only positive node weights, which means that a shortest path will have no repetition of nodes. As the cost does not depend on the nodes only, approaches like the [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) algorithm or the algorithm by [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) are not suitable.

That being said, apparently the path can be found recursively by using [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), where nodes which are currently occuring in the stack may not be visited. Every time the destination is reached, the current path (which is contained in the stack at each time the destination is reached) along with its associated cost, which could be maintained in an auxiliary variable, could be evaluated against the best previously found path. On termination, a path with minimum cost would be stored.

Comment: Hey @codor, Thanks much for writing. I appreciate the second solution. Maybe, I would have done the same. Also, I have added one more constraint in the question. Please take a look and suggest.